# How to retrieve image from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Datagridview in C# [Windows Application]

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, windows

Hi friends i have inserted image to Sql Server and i need to retrieve image from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Datagridview Column in C# [Windows Application].Is there any possible to show the image in Data Grid View is any Respective Size in a column of Grid View.

My Coding to Insert the images to SQL Server is :

```
  public void saveImageInDataBase(int imageid)
    {

        byte[] imagedata = ReadImageFile(txt_upload.Text);
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection();
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db_payroll;Integrated Security=True;";
        sqlconn.Open();
        string query = "insert into tbl_image values('"+imagedata+"')";
        MessageBox.Show(query);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rows > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image saved.");
            txt_upload.Text = "";
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to save image.");
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }

    public byte[] ReadImageFile(string imageLocation)
    {
        byte[] imageData = null;
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(imageLocation);
        long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
        return imageData;
    }
```

Please try to Solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store to DB (in DB the `imagedata` column must have `IMAGE` data type)

```
    string query = "insert into tbl_image values(@imagedata)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagedata", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
    cmd.Parameters["@imagedata"].Value = imagedata;
    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To retrieve from DB

```
    string query = "select imagedata from tbl_image where ID=@ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    byte[] imagedata=(byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: its works fine... can you tell me, how to fix the cell size to 100 X 100 and image style should be as stretch.

Comment: @coolprarun For this you can use `Ask Question` button and create new thread with appropriate title.